# How to have a list of clickable HyperLinks in a GridViewColumn of a ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, hyperlink

I am trying to bind a list of objects to a list of `HyperLinks` that are comma-separated, and clickable.

I can do it if it's only one of them per cell, but I don't know how to bind a collection per cell.

Something like this in a single `GridViewColumn` cell:

```
Effect01, Effect02, Effect02, Shader01. Shader02
```

where clicking any of them will call the binded object's `Execute` method.

Each element is:

```
public class EffectLink : IExecutable
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public void Execute ();
}
```

as enforced by `IExecutable`.

I do it this way because the behaviour of `Execute` will depend on whether it's a shader, an effect, etc.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I found that I could do this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink>Effect01</Hyperlink>
    <Hyperlink>Effect02</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

So this shows 2 space-separate hyperlinks in a single cell.

Also this question might be related, but it shows how do it in code, not xaml:
[Nested TextBlocks and Hyperlinks, How do you replicate this XAML in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573382/nested-textblocks-and-hyperlinks-how-do-you-replicate-this-xaml-in-c/1573498#1573498)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put an `ItemsControl` in your `GridViewColumn.CellTemplate`

```
    <GridViewColumn >
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="commaTextBlock" Text=", " />
                                <TextBlock><Hyperlink><Run Text="{Binding Path=Name}" /></Hyperlink></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="commaTextBlock" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        </DataTemplate>

                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks, one thing that's different is the Effects collection is inside the ObservableCollection<GraphNode> so Effects is a property for each GraphNode. Do you know how I can bind it to this collection? Currently ListView ItemsSource is set to ObservableCollection<GraphNode>, so these hyperlinks should be generated from each GraphNode.Effects collection. Does it make sense?

Comment: instead of `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">` you'd have `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Effects}">`

Comment: also, you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511227/how-can-a-separator-be-added-between-items-in-an-itemscontrol to properly display commas rather than the spaces my XAML has

Comment: @qntmfred: Thanks a lot, it works great. Didn't take any fiddling to get it working. Also I was experimenting with your xaml to add commas that aren't hyper links, so just like yours but with ", " but replacing `Run Text=" "` with `Run Text=", "` made the link part of the hyperlink. I understand why but do you know if it's possible to have the commas as non-clickable texts? Thanks again.

Comment: Just saw your new post, like you read my mind :O Will check out your link now.

Comment: I tried what's shown in your link and it works, but there is a space after the item name, so it looks like this: "effect01" ,"effect02" , etc. I used this xaml:                                                         `<Hyperlink><Run Text="{Binding Path=Name}" /><Run Text="" />
                                                        </Hyperlink>
                                                        <TextBlock Text=","/>` Btw I left the `Run Text=""` for flexibility if I needed to change in the future. But still it's empty string.

Comment: Also if that formatting can't be done, it's not a big deal. Although I was wondering if you could also show me if it's possible to run a method inside the type each hyperlink is binded to when the link is clicked? I think I can do it if it has to be done on the code side, but if it would be specified on the xaml side, I think that would be better because I wouldn't have to try to find which link is clicked when the event is called, etc.

Comment: updated the xaml for the commas and the extra hyperlink padding you mentioned

Comment: you can bind `HyperLink.Command` to an `ICommand` on your EffectLink object which can call your Execute() method

Comment: Thanks qntmfred, it works great. I am binding the command to the method but it says that there is no property called Execute. Is the syntax to bind to methods different? But I don't mind restricting it IExecutable/ICommand because that's what I want.

Comment: well, you probably need to make a property on EffectLink called ExecuteCommand of type ICommand, and use something like a [RelayCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) to hook the ExecuteCommand to your Execute method, then your HyperLink binding would look like Command="{Binding Path=ExecuteCommand}"

Comment: Thanks qntmfred, I did it like you said and it works. But all this RelayCommand and stuff, are they not generic/common enough to be part of WPF? Or is this just another implementation of ICommand. Thanks again man, I wish I could give you more points.